# Installing Magento2 Extension over SSH (terminal)?

Tags: magento2

How to install magento2 extension over SSH?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > 1. Connect to your magento webserver using ssh
> >        To do this, run the following command in the terminal and enter user password (please skip this step if youre installing expansion on the local machine):

ssh username@domain.com

> > 2. Change your current directory to Magento 2 web root directory

Run command:

cd /full_path_to_magento2

> > 3. Start setup process

Run command:

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

> > 4. Run the single-tenant compiler

Run Command:

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

> > 5. Deploy static view files

Run Command:

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

> > 6. All done
> >        Now you can navigate to your magento 2 admin panel and start configuring your extension

Answer (score 1):

You have to just run below command,

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

After run this command,

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Remove var folder.